# Animation movie (80's-90's) with brain-sucking insects

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a movie I've seen as a kid, the details are foggy and sparse but I'll try my best following [the guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question):

- ***What is it?***: An animated movie.
- ***Tell us what it isn't***: It is not [Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)).
- ***Tell us what made it memorable***: A planet where some brain-sucking insect-like aliens live, also an old bald man lives on the same planet.
- ***When did you see this film?***: Late 80's, early 90's.
- ***How old was it?***: If I've seen the movie on TV in Spain, is a pretty safe bet that it will be at least 5 years old.
- ***Was it part of a series?***: I don't think so.
- ***Plot***: No clue, sorry.
- ***What language was it in?***: The movie was dubbed to Spanish (Spain).

#### No detail is too insignificant

- *What details can I recall?*:

  - Sci-Fi story with one character being an old bald man living on a planet where some insect-ish aliens can open your skull and suck your brain.
  - Habitat of those insect-ish foes was depicted in light blue colors, I kinda remember giant mushrooms as well.
  - A young boy befriends the old baldie, the boy came to the planet with some adults.
- *Other details I'm not completely sure (maybe my mind is filling the gaps)*:

  - I think that the movie was drawn using [rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping), not 100% sure though.
  - I cannot remember which year I've seen the movie, but it should be late 80's or early 90's.
  - I'm pretty sure that I've seen the movie in Spanish TV (not rented videotape).
  - Somehow the young boy was the young version of the old baldie (time travel?).
  - The old man lives in a wood house near the brain-sucking insect habitat, as many old man does he spend his time on the porch.

#### Try to offer unique details

As anyone would expect from this kind of movie, there's a scene where the alien insects attack a group of people trying to suck their brains. A young boy was with those adults and survived with injuries in his head.

The old bald man have some surgery in his head due to an attack he suffered years before.

Comment: This is probably one of the best story IDs I've seen, +1 and well done spotting the guide!

Comment: I caught this movie on TV by accident when I was a kid and I've never forgotten it. It has a great plot-twist ending. I recall the old man was on the spaceship, rather than living on the planet - but I watched it a long time ago...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using the web site [What is my Movie?](https://www.whatismymovie.com/) and using the keywords `animation+movie+insect+brains` I scrolled down and look at something that could resemble that movie.

This is [*Time Masters*](https://www.whatismymovie.com/item?item=0084315) (1982) (French: *Les Maîtres du temps*).

[image: Insect attack]

This is the trailer:

Comment: It absolutely looks like it could be!! The picture you posted looks like the boy being injured in the head by the attack of the insect-like aliens, as I remember! Also [searching for more pictures of the movie](http://cubbi.org/temps/) make me recall even more things about it, worth to mention [the insects attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kniyqWX8aPY) as well. **good job!**.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately recognised the movie upon your description, and indeed, this is "The Time Masters", a French-Hungarian co-production animated movie.
I remember how scared I was from the tentacles in the cave. And the faceless angels were also were quite frightening.

But the egg-shaped walkie talkie was cool :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything of substance to the existing answer.

Comment: @Politank-Z it adds that "the egg-shaped walkie talkie was cool" :P