# Vaguely remember a cartoon in the 1980s- Blue thing (pet/travel companion)

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have this vague memory from the 80's of watching a cartoon. It was quite long (not sure if it was a series or not), and the only things I kind of remember about it are:-

1. At some point they (boy and blue pet thing) land on a planet. I think the blue pet thing then gets trapped in a cave by these tentacle things and is eaten...it was sad
2. At some other point in the cartoon, a planet is visited where they converse with a whole load of angel type beings that exist in a massive bubble.

The whole thing reminds me of French / Manga style. I also seem to remember that it was on TV around the same time as Ulysses 31 and had a similar style.

Comment: I suspect this is (once again) *Time Masters* / *Les Maîtres du temps*, which comes up here a lot for some reason (see for example [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246918/space-themed-cartoon-film-seen-on-tv-in-the-mid-80s-with-a-pair-of-blobby-telep/246957) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil) among others).

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188278/animation-movie-80s-90s-with-brain-sucking-insects

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly ***[The Masters of Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084315/)*** (1982).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps):

> *Les Maîtres du temps* (lit. *The Masters of Time*, a.k.a. *Time Masters*, *Herrscher der Zeit* in German, *Az idő urai* in Hungarian) is a 1982 Franco-West German-Swiss-British-Hungarian animated science fiction feature film directed by René Laloux and designed by Mœbius. It is based on the 1958 science fiction novel *L'Orphelin de Perdide* (*The Orphan of Perdide*) by Stefan Wul.
>
> The film centres on a boy, Piel, who is stranded on Perdide, a desert planet where giant killer hornets live. He awaits rescue by the space pilot Jaffar, the exiled prince Matton, his sister Belle and Jaffar's old friend Silbad who are trying to reach Perdide and save Piel before it is too late.

There's a scene around the [56:59](https://youtu.be/Vc4nNhwWBJc?t=3487) mark where the boy and an alien creature he's riding wander into a cave, and the creature is entwined and killed by tentacles descending from the ceiling of the cave. The creature isn't blue, but the boy does interact with a blue and white creature earlier in the film, around the [22:48](https://youtu.be/Vc4nNhwWBJc?t=1368) mark.

There's also a scene around the [44:26](https://youtu.be/Vc4nNhwWBJc?t=2666) mark with a number of angel-like beings and an amorphous alien resembling a large energy bubble. The 'angels' were actually a variety of beings whose individuality had been absorbed by the alien, causing them to transform into identical, faceless and voiceless, angel-like entities. Once the alien was defeated, they returned to their original forms.